# Alternative to document.getElementById().setAttribute() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any alternative to doing the following line:

```
 document.getElementById("btn").setAttribute("onclick", "save(" + id + ");");
```

This line basically changes the `onclick()` event of a button to something like: `save(34); , save(35);` etc. However it fails in IE 7 and 6 but works in IE 8 and Firefox.

I can use jquery for this as well.

Comment: Not sure, but I think you are doing it wrong in the first place. What are you trying to accomplish? You have this Id, why not get the id inside the save() method instead of setting it in a static way ?

Comment: If you can use jQuery, I don't think there is ever a point in using document.getElementById() anymore

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can use jQuery, then:

```
$("#btn").click(function() { save(id); })
```

Answer (score 10):

**Plain old javascript:**

```
var myButton = document.getElementById("btn");
myButton.onclick = function()
{
  save(id); //where does id come from?
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    save(id); //where does id come from?
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this one :

```
$("#btn").bind('click', function() { save(id); });
```